# Adding xen domains to virsh

Tags: python, xen, libvirt, virsh

Basic problem:

I had task like this : I need to collect metrics with diamond collector from Xen. Collector used libvirt python library and just doest find any xen domains for output information. Thats because libvirt get information from virsh which doesnt find xen domains.

What i did: I converted xen cfg into virsh xml due this command ‘virsh domxml-from-native xen-xm /path/to/xm-or-xl.config’ and defined domains.

Now:

```
way@xen4-dom0:/etc/libvirt/domains$ sudo virsh list --all
Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
-     gitlab                         shut off
-     stage-pg-master                shut off
-     stage-rzd-tnved                shut off
-     stage-web-transport            shut off
```

Xen:

```
way@xen4-dom0:/opt/metrics/rrd$ sudo xen list
Name             ID      Mem VCPUs  State   Time
Domain-0         0       1024 8     r-----  165814.0
stage-pg-master  1       16384 4    -b----   37170.7
.....
```

But when i trying to start domains got following errro:

```
libxenlight failed to create new domain 'gitlab'
```

libx log said:

```
domain with name "gitlab" already exists.
```

How to resolve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Additional question : How to add Domain-0 to virsh ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem cant be resloved, so i just changed diamond xen collector source.